# Creating a new action

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I've inherited a symfony project and I'm trying to create a new action.

I've gone to the `/frontend/modules/theModuleName/actions/actions.class.php` file and created a new function (there are already several in there) and followed the naming guideline of calling it `executeFunctionName`.

However, when I try to call it from a template like so:

`<form action="/frontend_dev.php/theModuleName/functionName" method="post">` I just get errors and it doesn't work.

What else needs to be done to create a new action?

Comment: What is the difference with your other question? [How to create an action in symfony?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328813/how-to-create-an-action-in-symfony)

Comment: None. Didn't get any replies so I tried wording it differently hours later. Feel free to close. I got it working anyway. Apparently you need a corresponding template.

Comment: Well, delete the one you think is less constructive and then post an answer to the other one and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by errors you mean 404 (not found). That only works if you still have the default routing rules:

```
default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

Otherwise just make a rule. something like this:

```
my_route:
  url: /my-custom-url.html
  param: { module: theModuleName, action: functionName }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in what errors I was getting. I am getting `500 | Internal Server Error | sfRenderException
The template "actionSuccess.php" does not exist or is unreadable in "".`

Comment: As the error message says you don't have a template for the action so create the /frontend/modules/theModuleName/templates/actionSuccess.php file.

Comment: what erdeszt means, its you need a template with the name of the method (function) and Success suffix: functionNameSuccess.php in your module's template folder.